# What are the concerns of usability or accessibility on using a custom scrollbar in a webpage?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, user-experience

Posted this question a while back but it got close as opinion-based? I now have an answer.

What are the benefits to customize scrollbar for a webpage in relation to user experience?

Would if affect the user experience badly in any way? if Yes how ?

Is there any relation between custom scrollbar in relation to the site content and user age ? For example, cartoons game sites can have custom scrollbar to reflect the site content in a positive way

Comment: this may still get closed as opinion based bud, stackoverflow expects **coding** problems that people can help you with. The above is 'opinion based' as people believe a question like this is too open to different opinions. I have answered below as I believe it is a valid question but if it gets closed try a different stack exchange such as https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

With custom scroll bars you want to follow the same guidelines as if you were creating a custom component.

So colour contrast is your main concern - as a minimum the `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` should have a contrast ratio of at least 3:1 with the `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`.

Also ensure that the scroll bar background has contrast with you page colour (so if your page is predominantly white, make the scroll bar a 3:1 ratio with the page if you can.)

Additionally don't make the scroll bar thinner than it is already using

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px; /* don't do this as you make the scroll bar harder to click with a mouse for those with accuracy issues.
}
```

Other than that feel free to change scrollbar colours, in fact if you want to make your scroll bar more accessible then why not make it extra wide so it is easier to click (if you could make it work a `48px` wide scroll bar would actually make it comply with the same rules we apply to minimum sizes for buttons, but it does look a bit odd!).